# Echo bot I deployed in Azure is not running. "There was an error sending this message to your bot."

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

I used the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/02.echo-bot) Node JS typescript version of code to deploy an echobot.
Before doing that I created Azure Bot and Web app resources, where the Bot is UserAssignedMSI. I did connect Web App to the bot through identity. I have set the messenging endpoint '/api/messages' with https. I did put all the values in the .env file, except the password since this is a user assigned. Followed everything in the Azure's documentation of Publish and Deploy. But there is no echoed response. The bot is supposed to give the welcome message and echo my response but nothing! When I check channels -> directline or web chat, I get "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound" error. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you getting the output when tested in local using Bot Framework Emulator?

Comment: not at all, I heard that by using UserAssignedMSI, we normally don't get the response. I do get the response if the credentials are not provided.

Comment: No, by using UserAssignedMSI also we will get the output as shown here in this screenshot-https://i.imgur.com/qxaEA7n.png